# Diff for 3 binary files

Tags: macos, vim, diff, binaryfiles

I have 3 binary files. Let's call them `file1.bin`, `file2.bin` and `file3.bin`.

- `file1.bin` and `file2.bin` have some common parts.
- `file2.bin` and `file3.bin` have some common parts.

I want to find the common parts between `file1.bin` and `file2.bin` that are different between `file2.bin` and `file3.bin`.

How do you recommend to accomplish that? I have already dumped the binary files to text files using `xxd` and then did a 3-way diff using `vim -d file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`.

However, `vim` marks a part as changed in all the files even if it has only changed in one file and remains the same in the other two files. I want those special kind of occurrences to be marked differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the built-in unix diff (I think it is part of OSX), but use the `--unchanged-group-format` to list the similarities. Do that for file1 and file 2. Then do it for file2 and file3. You can then do a regular diff on the two resulting files.

For an idea of how to get the similarities, have a look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/output-the-common-lines-similarities-of-two-text-files-the-opposite-of-diff).

Answer (score 0):

The tool that I work for ([ECMerge](http://www.elliecomputing.com)) does that. You just have to diff the 3 binary files, it will present equal portions in front of each other, and modified bytes appropriately placed in between. No need to first get an hex dump. You can script in JavaScript to output whatever you like based on the diff results and the bytes in the files (it works also in command line).

Answer (score -1):

Chromium uses [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/), then switched to courgette for doing binary diff as explained in their blog [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/07/smaller-is-faster-and-safer-too.html). You might find useful leads from their blog.

Comment: Can it do 3 way diffs in the way I described in the problem? I can't find out how, would you please describe that?

Comment: bsdiff works on binary files, and produces binary patch. vimdiff expect text files as its input so I can't think of a way to make bsdiff works the way you would like here. As an alternative, see if you can make use of the ``'diffexpr'`` option to coax vim to use extra setting for the diff program when generating the  hunks for the binary files - maybe use the ``-I`` option to ``diff`` to specify a regex for "lines" that should be ignored when doing diff.